# add 0 before number if < 10

Tags: c#, if-statement

This is my code:

```
string Unreadz = "0";
while (true)
{
    Unreadz = CheckMail();       
    if (!Unreadz.Equals("0")) port.Write("m");
    else port.Write("n");
}
```

If `Unreadz` is less than `10`, I want to add a `0` before it, before `port.write`.

This is what I have tried:

```
if (Unreadz < 10) port.Write("0" + Unreadz);
else port.Write("" + Unreadz);
```

but it doesn't work because `Unreadz` is a string.

Comment: use the Unreadz.length if you are interested in length or parse it to an integer like Int32.Parse(unreadz) if you want the numeric value stored inside the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its guaranteed that the return value will be an integer represented as string, then you can convert it to a number and then perform comparison.

```
if ( Convert.ToInt32(Unreadz) < 10 ) port.Write("0" + Unreadz);
else port.Write("" + Unreadz);
```

Comment: worked better than the higher ranked answer...maybe because of my inexperience... but thanks!

Comment: @Csharpz care to explain how it worked better? Did you get any error using the one line way?

Answer (score 23):

This should work:

```
port.Write(Unreadz.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
```

Answer (score 10):

```
string.Format("{0:00}", 9);
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=VS.71).aspx

More directly you can:

```
  9.ToString("00"); // "09"
 19.ToString("00"); // "19"
119.ToString("00"); // "119"
```

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an integer, the ToString method will help you:

```
int i = 5;
string formatted = i.ToString("00");
```

formatted will be **05**
you can do this for as many '0' as you want, and also put extra characters if your end string is different:

```
int minutes = 2, seconds = 3;
int timeSum = minutes * 100 + seconds;
string time = timeSum.ToString("00m00s");
```

time will be **02m03s**

Answer (score 5):

try

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Unreadz) < 10) port.Write(string.format("{0}{1}", "0", Unreadz);
```

Alternatively,

```
if (Unreadz.length == 1 ) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `Unreadz` should really be an int, not a string

Then you can write:

```
        int Unreadz;
        while (true)
        {
            Unreadz = CheckMail(); //Change this to return an int

            string formattedNumber = String.Format("{0:##}", Unreadz.ToString());
            port.Write(formattedNumber); 
        }
```

Comment: You don't even need the `.ToString()` - String.Format will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to a number to do the test for less than 10:

```
// this will throw an exception if the string does not contain a number
int unreadzNumber = int.Parse(Unreadz);
```

If you are certain that the string contains exactly one digit and nothing else, you can just test if it has length 1:

```
bool isLessThanTen = Unreadz.Length == 1;
```

You can do the formatting in a variety of different manners:

```
// 1: just stick a zero before it
string formatted = string.Format("0{0}", unreadzNumber);
// 2: use a special format string to use at least two digits
string formatted = string.Format("{0:00}", unreadzNumber);
// 3: pad the string with zeros to the left
string formatted = Unreadz.PadLeft(2, '0');
// 4: manually concatenate with "0"
string formatted = "0" + Unreadz;
// and probably others
```

I prefer the second one because it makes the format clearer and easier to maintain and does not require the comparison.

So, you get:

```
   string Unreadz = "0";
    while (true)
    {
        Unreadz = CheckMail();       
        int unreadzNumber = int.Parse(Unreadz);
        port.Write(string.Format("{0:00}", unreadzNumber));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now specify format in an interpolated string:

```
string myOutput = $"{myNumber:00}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If Unreadz is a string, then to compare it, you would have to convert it to an int.

if (Unreadz < 10)
to
if (Convert.ToInt16(Unreadz) < 10)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `int unreadz` and then use `port.Write(string.Format("{0:00}", unreadz)`